# Como armazenar informação em um arquivo em Python (write)?

Tags: python, fortran

Olá,
Eu estou escrevendo um programa em Python com um código que tenho em Fortran.
Estou com um problema para escrever esse trecho (do fortran):

```
do i=1,n
write(3,350)r(i),(ener(j)*alfa,j=1,6) !meV

end do
```

Eu tentei escrever desta forma em Python:

```
file=open("energia_nll2_R50A.dat","w")
for i in range(1,n+1):
  for j in range(1,6):
    file.write("r[i],(ener[j]*alfa)")
file.close()
```

Eu queria saber se tem mais uma forma equivalente de escrever esse trecho em Python.

Código completo:

```
alfa = 3014.4
r = []
for i in range(1,n1+1):
  x = r1 + (i - 1)*hr1
  r.append(x)
ener = []
for i in range(1,n):
  for j in range(i+1,n+1):
    if ener[i]>ener[j]:
      az = ener[j]
      ener[j] = ener[i]
      ener[i] = az
      for k in range(1,n+1):
        zz3 = vetor[k,j]
        vetor[k,j] = vetor[k,i]
        vetor[k,i] = zz3

file=open("energia_nll2_R50A.dat","w")
for i in range(1,n+1):
  for j in range(1,6):
    file.write("r[i],(ener[j]*alfa)")
file.close()
```

Comment: Você quer que os valores de i e j apareçam no arquivo? O que são `r`, `ener`, `alfa` e `n`?

Comment: i e j aqui são referentes ao número de vetores a aparecerem no arquivo.

Comment: alfa é um número, n é a precisão e r e ener são os vetores

Comment: Eu queria saber também se está certa essa forma de referenciar vetores dentro do write... porque não encontrei nada sobre.

Comment: E eles estão definidos no Python? Coloque o código completo, por favor.

Comment: Pronto, editei o post.

Comment: Ok, revejo minhas palavras. Seu código não fez sentido, então explique com palavras o que pretende fazer. Descreva qual é a sua entrada, quais os cálculos que deseja fazer e qual é a saída esperada.

Comment: Só uma dúvida, você está fazendo um cabeçalho aqui? file.write("r[i],(ener[j]*alfa)") ? Ou está tentando escrever os valores de r[i] e ener[j]*alfa no arquivo ?

Comment: Estou tentando escrevê-los no arquio. Para os 6 níveis de energia (que é esse "ener"). Trata-se da variação do raio "r" para os 6 níveis de energia "ener". No arquivo do Fortran que eu abria no Qtiplot, ficavam os 6 niveis de energia, um em cada coluna - repetindo o mesmo número para um dado nível, n vezes, nas linhas. Eu preciso disso para plotar o gráfico de energia.

Answer (score 0):

Oi, sim é possível escrever. Vamos por parte.

```
file=open("energia_nll2_R50A.dat","w")
for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(1,6):
        file.write("r[i],(ener[j]*alfa)")
file.close()
```

Primeiro vamos mudar o **"w"** por **"w+"**, assim quando enquanto escrevemos no arquivo, os dados do ficheiro não serão sobrescritos.

Depois vamos construir uma variável só para ficar mais legível.

```
conteudo = "%.f,%.f" %(r[i],ener[j]*alfa) # Caso os parentesis seja necessario, pode adicionar no segundo %.f
```

Então o trecho do código ficaria assim.

```
file=open("energia_nll2_R50A.dat","w")
for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(1,6):
        conteudo = "%.f,%.f" %(r[i],ener[j]*alfa)
        file.write(conteudo)
file.close()
```

## Agora sobre o código completo, como nao sei todas as variáveis deve ficar assim:

```
### Variáveis com alguns valores para poder testar.

n1 = 33
r1 = 2.321
hr1 = 0.456
n = 33

##################

alfa = 3014.4
r = []
for i in range(1,n1+1):
  x = r1 + (i - 1)*hr1
  r.append(x)

ener = [] # Como esta variável está vazia, acho que você insere alguma coisa nela, porém como não está escrito, assume-se uma lista com valores aleatórios.


### Como não vi a variável vetor, então criei uma, do tipo dicionário.
### Pois ela aceita um índice do tipo tupla. " (k,i) " or " k,i "

vetor={} # Porém não sei os valores que você guarda nela. Se você adicionar o mais informações eu completo a resposta.

##################

for i in range(1,n):
  for j in range(i+1,n+1):
    if ener[i]>ener[j]:
      az = ener[j]
      ener[j] = ener[i]
      ener[i] = az
      for k in range(1,n+1):
        zz3 = vetor[k,j]
        vetor[k,j] = vetor[k,i]
        vetor[k,i] = zz3

file=open("energia_nll2_R50A.dat","w+")
for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(1,6):
        conteudo = "%.f,%.f" %(r[i],ener[j]*alfa)
        file.write(conteudo)
file.close()
```

Assim já deve funcionar. Qualquer coisa só perguntar.